# IPv6 routing issues with Vodafone CZ modem

Tags: network-manager, 23.04, ipv6, vodafone

IPv6 used to work for me but something must have changed either in Ubuntu/Xubuntu or in the ISP (Vodafone CZ) modem about two months ago.

When I set the Network Manager UI to "Automatic", it starts cycling, disabling networking after few seconds, because Network Manager does not like something about IPv6. I have turned on debug logging for NetowrkManger.service but I don't exactly see what it does not like.

If I set NetworkManager to use DHCPv6, it gets me IPv6 address but I do not seem to get any IPv6 route. I can see `nm-dispatcher[140166]: req:6 'up' [enp6s0]: environment: IP6_GATEWAY=0.0.0.0`. And any attempts to ping IPv6 address fails. I can also see that it sets `accept_ra` to 0. I can also see `NetworkManager[2121]: <debug> [1691697302.1991] platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp6s0/accept_ra' to '0' (current value is identical)`, if it matters.

I am stumped. Is anyone able to get IPv6 working with Vodafone Czechia?